Why am I getting “Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'” when validating this JSON?
I am trying to make a variation of the piston made with cobbled deepslate instead of cobblestone. I am trying to get all of the block states and permutations done before I work on functionality, but I am getting errors. My block.json file looks like this:
{
    "format_version": "1.20.20",
    "minecraft:block": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "redstone:deepslate_piston",
            "states": {
                "redstone:extended": [ true, false ]
            },
            "menu_category": {
                "category": "items"
            },
            "traits": {
                "minecraft:placement_direction": {
                    "enabled_states": ["minecraft:facing_direction"]
                }
            }
        },
        "components": {
            "minecraft:collision_box": true,
            "minecraft:selection_box": true,
            "minecraft:destructible_by_mining": {
                "seconds_to_destroy": 1
            },
            "minecraft:destructible_by_explosion": {
                "explosion_resistance": 30
            },
            "minecraft:geometry": "geometry.deepslate_piston",
            "minecraft:material_instances": {
                "*": {
                    "texture": "deepslate_piston",
                    "render_method": "alpha_test"
                }
            },
            "minecraft:map_color": "#ffffff"
        },
        "permutations": [
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “north“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 180, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “south“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “east“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 90, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “west“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 270, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “up“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [-90, 0, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “down“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [90, 0, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“redstone:extended“) == “true“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:geometry": { 
                        "identifier": "geometry:extended_deepslate_piston"
                    }
                    "minecraft:material_instances": {
                    "*": {
                        "texture": "extended_deepslate_piston",
                        "render_method": "alpha_test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state(“redstone:extended“) == “false“ ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:geometry": { 
                        "identifier": "geometry:deepslate_piston"
                    }
                    "minecraft:material_instances": {
                    "*": {
                        "texture": "deepslate_piston",
                        "render_method": "alpha_test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

and I get this in the content log:
[Json][error]-block_definitions | /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB7FBFD6-7B5A-4E78-A1F5-42E84F0B0575/Documents/games/com.mojang/development_behavior_packs/Redstone_BP | blocks/deepslate_piston.block.json | upgrade blocks/deepslate_piston.block.json | failed to parse file into a json document: Missing a comma or '}' after an object member.

[Blocks][error]-block_definitions | /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB7FBFD6-7B5A-4E78-A1F5-42E84F0B0575/Documents/games/com.mojang/development_behavior_packs/Redstone_BP | blocks/deepslate_piston.block.json | Unexpected version for the loaded data

[Texture][warning]-The block named deepslate_piston used in a "blocks.json" file does not exist in the registry

After running it through a json validator I get
Invalid JSON!
Error: Parse error on line 90:
...ton"                 }                   "minecraft:material_...
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

Looking online, it looks like the most common cause of this is not having everything in a single set of {} braces, but this code doesn’t miss any as far as I can tell. It was working without the last two permutation conditions and extended state, but removing them hasn’t fixed it, so I probably messed something up.

you're missing a few commas near the end.
in JSON, if you don't close an object with ] or }, that means you're continuing to stuff it with additionnal sub-objects. when you do this, the json spec says you MUST add a comma between the 2 objects.
at the end of your json, you have this object:
{
    "condition": "q.block_state(“redstone:extended“) == “false“ ",
    "components": {
        "minecraft:geometry": { 
            "identifier": "geometry:deepslate_piston"
        }
        "minecraft:material_instances": {
            "*": {
                 "texture": "deepslate_piston",
                 "render_method": "alpha_test"
            }
        }
    }
}


notice how you're closing the "minecraft:geometry" object. since you haven't yet closed the "components" object, this means that the next thing you do MUST be either closing it (which would require a '}'), or adding another sub-object, which requires a comma. When the parser encounters "minecraft:material_instances", it barfs because it is none of those 2 things. you have the same error in the other similar block. add a comma before "minecraft:material_instances".

Now I get this: [Molang][error]-block_definitions | blocks/deepslate_piston.block.json | redstone:deepslate_piston | components | q.block_state(“minecraft:facing_direction“) == “north“  | unrecognized token: “minecraft:facing_direction“) == “north“
[Blocks][error]-block_definitions | blocks/deepslate_piston.block.json | redstone:deepslate_piston | components | permutation condition failed to parse
[Blocks][error]-block_definitions | blocks/deepslate_piston.block.json | Unexpected version for the loaded data

Okay, I figured that part out. I had my molang in “ instead of ‘. I’m still having issues, but this answered that specific question so I’ll go ahead and mark it.
